# помогите discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я делаю своего дискорд бота и я решил сделать команду .name <@user> и бот должен выводить имя БЕЗ тега пользователя которого я упомянул и я не знаю как это сделать помогите пожалуйста!
пример:
name0: .name @name2#2379
bot:name2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите атрибуты для класса member и выберите подходящий
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#member

Comment: можете привести пример?